# USB serial device stopped being recognized by Windows 10, i.e. does not show up in Device Manager as a COM port

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I have a [GNSS/RTK receiver](https://www.ardusimple.com/product/simplertk2b-basic-starter-kit-ip65/) that is connected to a Microsoft Surface 3 and registers as a USB serial device. It used to show up in device manager as a COM port and I could communicate with it. This stopped working overnight. The GNSS receiver no longer shows up in device manager, but when I plug it in, Windows still plays the "USB-plugged-in" jingle.

I have verified that the GNSS receiver itself is not faulty by plugging it into another PC, where drivers were promply automatically installed, the receiver is visible in device manager and I can connect and communicate with it properly.

I have also checked that the Surface can still recognize USB serial devices in general by plugging an Arduino Uno in, which worked as expected.

I suspect that the drivers for the GNSS receiver somehow became corrupted. I tried to fix this by activating "Show hidden devices" in device manager and uninstalling the drivers of the greyed out USB serial devices in hopes that this would lead to automatic reinstallation of drivers when the GNSS receiver is next plugged in. This did not work though and had no discernible effect whatsoever.

Although the [official documentation](https://www.ardusimple.com/simplertk2b-hookup-guide/) explicitly states that no drivers need to be downloaded for Windows 10 I tried to download and install the drivers indicated on that page, but that didn't help either.

Is there a way to further diagnose and fix the problem?

Comment: Some time ago there was a manufacturer of USB-serial chips that also provides a good USB Windows driver. This manufacturer was annoyed that so many Chinese manufacturer sell similar USB-serial chips but do not develop an own driver, instead use the existing of that  annoyed company. Therefore they changed the driver to recognize their chips and don't work with the Chinese copies. May be your device has such a Chinese copy inside...

Comment: I'd hope not, I think the seller I bought it from should be reputable. Also, if that was the case, shouldn't the device never have worked in the first place? I used it without problems for several weeks.

Comment: Do you happen to know how and if I can double check that?

Comment: I managed to get it working again. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1669115/1236710) on my other question for the steps I took.