# How to locate and remove drivers for a USB serial device that is no longer recognized by windows?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I have a USB serial device that is no longer recognized by Windows. I have checked that the device itself still works on another PC, so I suspect a corrupted driver.

The [documentation](https://www.ardusimple.com/simplertk2b-hookup-guide/) for the device explicitly states that it is not necessary to manually download and install a driver. When the device was first plugged in a driver was automatically installed.

I would like to remove the currently installed driver in hopes that it will be reinstalled when the device is plugged in again.

I already tried activating "Show hidden devices" in Device Manager and uninstalling the driver from there, but that didn't help. Googling around it seems like the confirmation popup for driver deinstallation used to have a checkbox to remove the driver completely but that checkbox is no longer there.

How can I locate the currently installed driver so I can remove it?

Background: I am trying to solve the problem described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1668831/usb-serial-device-stopped-being-recognized-by-windows-10-i-e-does-not-show-up).

Comment: If the device once worked on the PC, and now doesn't, suspect that USBSTOR info in the Registry needs to be removed, rather than a driver. See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac09fc49-21d4-4d1e-843d-c6dcd3ad91f1/how-can-erase-all-history-of-usb-connected-drives-and-cdroms-from-my-registry

Comment: Try [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to locate and delete the device.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to use [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) by harrymc was a good one. While deleting the device using this program didn't help, I did notice that the device was using the wrong driver - WUDFRd.sys instead of usbser.sys.

I eventually found the device in the Device Manager under Sensors. There I tried to change the driver to the USB serial driver, which at first didn't work. The device now showed up as a COM port, but I could not communicate with it.

Only after running [USBOblivion](https://www.cherubicsoft.com/en/projects/usboblivion) and again updating the driver to USB serial by:

right-clicking the device in Device Manager -> Update driver -> Browse my computer for drivers -> Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer -> USB serial device

did it finally work again :)